# How do I change position of the commandbuttons on my VisualForce Page?

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">

    <style>
        p{
        font-size: 18px;
        color:blue;
        }

        h1{
        font-size: 26px;
        text-align:center;
        color:blue;
        }

        body{
        background-color:black;  
        background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif");
        background-repeat:repeat;
        }
    </style>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblocksection>
                <H1> SALESdb </H1>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock> 

        <apex:commandButton value="Login"   />
        <apex:commandButton value="Continue as a guest"  />

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I want to have those two buttons in the center as below

```
   Login
     or
Continue as Guest
```

I did look into other answers but those were a little too advanced for me,they were not simple as my problem to me is.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use style margin-top: 10%;

```
<center style="margin-top: 10%"> 
<apex:commandButton value="Login"/> <br/> Or <br/> 
<apex:commandButton value="Continue as Guest"/>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks this works, is there any link you can provide me because i can't find any thing when it comes to tags, i always feel left behind...

Comment: w3schools will helps you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<center>
        <apex:commandButton value="Login"/>
        <br/>
        Or
        <br/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Continue as Guest"/>
        </center>
```

Comment: Thanks , that works fine but it still on top, i dont want it on top i want it in the middle.Do you know how to position it down.How can I have full control of positioning any idea?

Comment: <center style="    vertical-align: middle;">
        <apex:commandButton value="Login"/>
        <br/>
        Or
        <br/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Continue as Guest"/>
        </center>

Comment: style=" vertical-align: middle;" this will allow you to controll it vertically as well

Comment: nope , same position as before.

Comment: please check this link and you can just replace <apex:commandButton value="Login"/> <br/> Or <br/> <apex:commandButton value="Continue as Guest"/> with 'Content goes here'  http://jsfiddle.net/pqDQB/

Comment: cool, i'll have a check

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your command button with a div and apply the attribute align="center"

```
<div align="center">
    <apex:commandButton value="Login"   />
</div>
<div align="center">
    <apex:commandButton value="Continue as a guest"  />
</div>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: it works , i mean it is in the centre but i want it to position it lower, how can i control it vertically, also how do i break line between them both buttons because it is all in the same line instead of top of another.

Comment: Wrap both the command button into two divs

Comment: thanks this works, although it doesn't lower it